# Insert element into an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach($key_doc_count as $item) {
    mb_language('Japanese');
    $product = $item["key"];
    $product_url = 'https://search.rakuten.co.jp/search/mall/'.urlencode($product) . '/';
    $source = file_get_contents($product_url);
    $source = mb_convert_encoding($source, 'utf8', 'auto');

    $rakuten_search_html = str_get_html($source);

    $count=0;
    foreach ($rakuten_search_html->find('img._verticallyaligned') as $item_image) {

        if(strlen($item_image->alt > 2))
        {
            $ss['image_url'] = $item_image->src;
            $ss['title'] = $item_image->alt;
            $items_kk[] = $ss;
            $count++;

            if($count <5)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $new_item["term"] = $item["key"];
    $new_item["current_count"] = $item["doc_count"];
    $new_item["results"] =  $terms_kk;
    $new_word_array[] = $new_item;
}

var_dump($new_word_array);
```

I am trying to insert the url and title of the product in an array names $ss and then assign that array to $new_term["result"] .

But its not working
The error was HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: where you declare `$ss` in code?

Comment: U are assigning value into `$items_kk` array. so change the line `$new_item["results"] =  $items_kk;` and check again.

Comment: what was the error or problem

Answer (score 0):

The variables `$items_kk` and `$new_word_array` seems to have not been initialized outside of the foreach loop. Try to init them as an empty array just before the loop :

```
$new_word_array = [];
foreach($key_doc_count as $item) {
mb_language('Japanese');
$product = $item["key"];
$product_url = 'https://search.rakuten.co.jp/search/mall/'.urlencode($product) . '/';
$source = file_get_contents($product_url);
$source = mb_convert_encoding($source, 'utf8', 'auto');

$rakuten_search_html = str_get_html($source);

$count=0;
$items_kk = [];
foreach ($rakuten_search_html->find('img._verticallyaligned') as $item_image) {

    if(strlen($item_image->alt > 2))
    {
        $ss['image_url'] = $item_image->src;
        $ss['title'] = $item_image->alt;
        $items_kk[] = $ss;
        $count++;

        if($count <5)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

$new_item["term"] = $item["key"];
$new_item["current_count"] = $item["doc_count"];
$new_item["results"] =  $terms_kk;
$new_word_array[] = $new_item;
}

var_dump($new_word_array);
```

Also, you're setting `$items_kk` and assigning `$terms_kk` to the new array. **It may be an error ?**